# the trait `StorableHint<ManualKey<1648493478>>` is not implemented

Tags: polkadot, ink, substrate-contracts-node

Can someone please help me figure our this issue?

[image]

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `ink::storage::Mapping<(ink::ink_primitives::AccountId, u64), u64, RequestUnstakingTimeKey>: StorableHint<ManualKey<1648493478>>` is not satisfied
  --> /Users/ganesholi/Developer/Build3rs/foxies/impls/staking/types.rs:33:33
   |
33 |     pub request_unstaking_time: Mapping<(AccountId, u64), u64, RequestUnstakingTimeKey>,
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `StorableHint<ManualKey<1648493478>>` is not implemented for `ink::storage::Mapping<(ink::ink_primitives::AccountId, u64), u64, RequestUnstakingTimeKey>`
   |
   = help: the trait `StorableHint<Key>` is implemented for `ink::storage::Mapping<K, V, InnerKey>`
   = note: required for `ink::storage::Mapping<(ink::ink_primitives::AccountId, u64), u64, RequestUnstakingTimeKey>` to implement `AutoStorableHint<ManualKey<1713486492, ManualKey<1648493478>>>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `ink::storage::Mapping<(ink::ink_primitives::AccountId, u64), u64, RequestUnstakingTimeKey>: StorableHint<ResolverKey<_, ManualKey<1713486492, ManualKey<1648493478>>>>` is not satisfied
  --> /Users/ganesholi/Developer/Build3rs/foxies/impls/staking/types.rs:33:33
   |
33 |     pub request_unstaking_time: Mapping<(AccountId, u64), u64, RequestUnstakingTimeKey>,
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `StorableHint<ResolverKey<_, ManualKey<1713486492, ManualKey<1648493478>>>>` is not implemented for `ink::storage::Mapping<(ink::ink_primitives::AccountId, u64), u64, RequestUnstakingTimeKey>`
   |
   = help: the trait `StorableHint<Key>` is implemented for `ink::storage::Mapping<K, V, InnerKey>`
   = note: required for `ink::storage::Mapping<(ink::ink_primitives::AccountId, u64), u64, RequestUnstakingTimeKey>` to implement `AutoStorableHint<ManualKey<1713486492, ManualKey<1648493478>>>`

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0277, E0407, E0425.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
warning: `foxies` (lib) generated 6 warnings
error: could not compile `foxies` due to 4 previous errors; 6 warniERROR: command ["/Users/ganesholi/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2023-02-07-aarch64-apple-darwin/bin/cargo", "build", "--color=always", "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown", "-Zbuild-std=core,alloc", "--no-default-features", "--release", "--target-dir=/Users/ganesholi/Developer/Build3rs/foxies/contracts/nft_contract/target/ink", "--features", "ink/ink-debug"] exited with code 101
ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air nft_contract %
```

This is my code link [github](https://github.com/Build3rs-Labs/foxies/blob/9b24d8308dc6e9157ee57614d6512fe7417c3d83/impls/staking/types.rs#L33)

Comment: What is the type for `RequestUnstakingTimeKey`? 
Check the format of the Mapping [here](https://docs.rs/ink/4.0.0/ink/storage/struct.Mapping.html)